# Junit @Rule and @ClassRule

Tags: java, junit, rule

I am writing JUnit4 test in which I am using TemporaryFolder rule. It seems that it works fine with both @Rule and @ClassRule. What is the difference between Junit @Rule and @ClassRule? Why should I use one and not another?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The distinction becomes clear when you have more than one test method in a class.

A `@ClassRule` has its `before()` method run before any of the test methods. Then all the test methods are run, and finally the rule's `after()` method. So if you have five test methods in a class, `before()` and `after()` will still only get run once each.

`@ClassRule` applies to a static method, and so has all the limitations inherent in that.

A `@Rule` causes tests to be run via the rule's `apply()` method, which can do things before and after the target method is run. If you have five test methods, the rule's `apply()` is called five times, as a wrapper around each method.

Use `@ClassRule` to set up something that can be reused by all the test methods, if you can achieve that in a static method.

Use `@Rule` to set up something that needs to be created a new, or reset, for each test method.

Comment: Simple, concise to the point –– Different from the official Javadoc. 

Thanks!

Comment: Hands down, one of the only few easy explanations that make sense on @ClassRule

Comment: how about just use annotations BeforeClass and Before? why ClassRule and Rule is needed?

Answer (score 3):

@Rule can not be set up to run before an @BeforeClass.

While @ClassRule must be on static method.

Answer (score 0):

Ref: Annotates static fields that reference rules or methods that return them. A field must be public, static, and a subtype of TestRule. A method must be public static, and return a subtype of TestRule.

The Statement passed to the TestRule will run any BeforeClass methods, then the entire body of the test class (all contained methods, if it is a standard JUnit test class, or all contained classes, if it is a Suite), and finally any AfterClass methods.

https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/ClassRule.html